# How to use a compound selector in CSS pseudo-class function :host-context(<selector>)

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom, pseudo-class

In the [`:host-context()` - MDN DOcs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host_function) it is stated that:

> The :host-context() CSS pseudo-class function selects the shadow host of the shadow DOM containing the CSS it is used inside (so you can select a custom element from inside its shadow DOM) — but only if the selector given as the function's parameter matches the shadow host's ancestor(s) in the place it sits inside the DOM hierarchy.
> In other words, this allows a custom element, or anything within that custom element's shadow DOM, to apply different styles based on its position within the outer DOM or classes/attributes applied to ancestor elements.

The problem though is that in the [live example](https://mdn.github.io/web-components-examples/host-selectors/) provided the `:host-context(article, aside) { color: gray; }` statement does not apply. Similarly, if I try to add other compound selectors that are space separated like `:host-context(h1 a){ background: orange}` I get the same issue of it not being applied.

Here are the examples given from the docs page

```css
/* Selects a shadow root host, only if it is
   a descendant of the selector argument given */
:host-context(h1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

:host-context(main article) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Changes paragraph text color from black to white when
   a .dark-theme class is applied to the document body */
p {
  color: #000;
}

:host-context(body.dark-theme) p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can get space separated selectors like descendant selectors to work as parameters in the `:host-context()` pseudo-class function?

I am expecting the `:host-context()` pseudo-class function to work with a parameter that is a space separated compound selector like `h1 a` since that is what is described in the docs page.

Thank you.

Comment: ``:host-context`` was a Google only party, not supported by the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was invalid code in the MDN example. A `<compound-selector>` or `<simple-selector>` are the only types that are accepted.

I made the change and the [pull request](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/28038) was approved

---

### Description

Removed invalid examples from docs.

Syntax from Docs

```
:host-context(<compound-selector>) {
  /* ... */
}
```

### Invalid Examples

```css
:host-context(article, aside) { color: gray; }
```

This is not valid because the argument provided to the `:host-context()` pseudo-class function is not a `<compound-selector>`. Rather, it is a "selector list" which is invalid and does not work in the live example.

```css
:host-context(main article) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is not valid because the argument provided to the `:host-context()` pseudo-class function is not a `<compound-selector>`. Rather, it is a `<complex-selector>` which is invalid and does not work in the live example.

This is explained in the [Structure of a Selector - CSS Selectors - MDN Docs Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#structure_of_a_selector)

### Motivation

The invalid CSS caused confusion when looking at the [live example](https://mdn.github.io/web-components-examples/host-selectors/)